# How to create shortcodes with options in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm struggling a bit to get my head around how to create shortcodes with options for a theme i'm building.

The shortcode creates a container and I want a "style" parameter so the user could enter something like this:

```
[container style="white"]content[/container]
```

I have three styles: white, clear and color and each style should add the class style1, style2 and style 3 respectively to the container html. This is what I have so far in my php:

```
// Container

function container($atts, $content = null) {
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'style' => 'style2',
     ), $atts ) );
    $return_string = '<section class="wrapper special container {$style}">'. do_shortcode($content) .'</section>';

    wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}
```

I just wanted to make a start by getting it to register 1 style but I can't even get to that point yet, let alone the three different styles!

Currently this just outputs:

```
<section class="wrapper special container {$style}">[MY CONTENT]</section>
```

in the html - any help or advise would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress get\_option from shortcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885007/wordpress-get-option-from-shortcode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1]** Try using a switch on the `$style` variable to echo out the corresponding `$return_string` depending on it's value.

**2]** Pay special attention to the `default:` case, as it is what will be displayed if `$style` is not set to `clear` or `white`. I set it to have no attribute, but you might want it to be different.

**3]** You can add as many cases as you need for the shortcode. Whatever the value of `$style` is will determine which `$return_string` is used.

```
function container($atts, $content = null) {
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'style' => '',
     ), $atts ) );

    switch ($style) {

        case "clear":
        $return_string = "<section class=\"wrapper special container style1\">". do_shortcode($content) ."</section>"; // Adds style1 if clear
        break;

        case "white":
        $return_string = "<section class=\"wrapper special container style2\">". do_shortcode($content) ."</section>"; // Adds style2 if white
        break;

        default:
        $return_string = "<section class=\"wrapper special container\">". do_shortcode($content) ."</section>"; // No Attribute (default)
        break;

        }
   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}
```

Comment: This gets me closer, currently the user has to write 'style1', 'style2' etc in the shortcode, whereas I want them to write 'clear' and the shortcode fill in 'style1' or 'white' and the shortcode fill in 'style2' etc

Comment: getting the following error: syntax error, unexpected ':' referring to the line with "case: "clear": on it